# Which possible methods can be used to determine if a certain part of the brain is active?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurology, brain, experimental-neuroscience

The question goes back to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JuliaHass/status/943517409322913795):

> Julia‏ @JuliaHass
>
> I just learned that elephants think humans are cute the way humans think puppies are cute (the same part of the brain lights up when they see us) so pack it in, nothing else this pure and good is happening today.

The [skeptics stack exchange post about the tweet refers to elephants](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40275/do-elephants-see-humans-the-same-way-humans-see-puppies), but I'm interested in a general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PET (positron emission tomography) will measure glucose consumption, e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2147116
- fMRI will measure changes in blood flow, or more precisely measuring the blood-oxygen-level dependent (BOLD) response. https://www.nature.com/scitable/blog/brain-metrics/what_does_fmri_measure

Note that I'm being a bit simplistic here, as with PET you can measure a lot of different things (like activation of circuits depending on specific neurotransmitters) depending on the tracer used. Here's a table from the book *PET and SPECT in Neurology*:

[image]

The downside is that PET has [lower spatial resolution than fMRI](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Functional_imaging) and substantially lower temporal resolution, meaning chnages over time are hard to pick up with PET. If you care about quick changes, then MEG or EEG are the fastest, but you have solve a difficult [inverse problem](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4614-7320-6_529-1) to figure out where the changes came from, which requires making quite a few assumptions to get a (unique) solution.

And let me add (for infotainment purposes) ["[f]MRI Killed The Radiotracer"](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/neuroskeptic/2013/08/30/fmri-killed-the-radiotracer/).

Comment: Just out of additional curiosity. Are you aware that any such diagnosis equipment is available for large animals such as elephants?

Comment: @jjack: I'm not sure. It would certainly require specialized equipment to scan live elephants because the usual scanners made for humans are too small. I did find one paper in which the brain of a recently deceased elephant went under MRI: http://allmanlab.caltech.edu/PDFs/Hakeem2005.pdf

Comment: @Fizz I haven't read the paper, but how can a dead brain function?

Comment: @Ooker: MRI (unlike **f**MRI) does not measure function, only anatomy.